# How to run an animation with delay while another animation in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I fade out the div (or animate its opacity to 0) over 1000 milliseconds after 4000 milliseconds in the last 1000 milliseconds of the div's animation (while the div is still moving)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function animateDiv(){
                $("div").animate({left:"500px"},5000);
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            div {
                background:red;
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
                position:relative;
                left:0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="animateDiv();">
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `step` in animate Or `progress` ?

Comment: The level of animation you're doing seems like a great choice for CSS animation.

Comment: This is not my animation Harangue, I just made a simple example. The example is irrelevant, my question isn't.

Comment: Rayon Dabre, thank you, I will read the documentation on this.

Comment: Something like this will help! `function animateDiv() {
   $("div").animate({
     left: "200px"
   }, {
     duration: 5000,
     step: function(now) {},
     progress: function(animation, progress, remainingMs) {}
   });
 }`

Comment: Satyaki Chatterjee, about your example, no, the div has to fade out "during" the animation, before the div stops.

Comment: SWEET! Thanks Rayon Dabre

Comment: @RayonDabre that was very informative. I think you should post an answer based on it. :-)

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, I will not mind if you edit your answer with that..Cheers ;)

Comment: @RayonDabre I'll do that.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, Just noticed that `queue: false,` plays vital role [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/zp5d0cg1/)

Comment: @RayonDabre yes. that is right, with out it the second animation waits till the first is complete.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, All of this comments can be wrapped in a useful answer...Go ahead  :)

Answer (score 2):

Note : **`queue:false`** is most important here.

Using `queue:false` you can run the animations simultaneously. Use [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function for [`fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) to wait. Which will give a smooth effect of the div slowly hiding when the left animation is coming to an end. Using `progress` we can identify the time left in the initial animation.

```js
function animateDiv() {
  $("div").animate({
    left: "500px"
  }, {
    duration:5000,
    queue:false
  }).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
}
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="animateDiv();">
  <div></div>
</body>
```

As an alternative( preferred solution ) like [Rayon Dabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746830/rayon-dabre) suggested, we can use the underlying functionalities of `animate()` function, we can use this to perfect it with out using `delay` and executing the second animation with the best time constraint as possible.

```js
var flag = true;
function animateDiv() {
  $("div").animate({
    left: "200px"
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 5000,
    step: function(now) { },
    progress: function(animation, progress, remainingMs) {
      if (remainingMs < 2000 && flag) {
        flag = false;
        $("div").fadeOut(1000);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="animateDiv();">
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Rejith R Krishnan. Works like a charm.

Comment: I did try the delay but without the "queue: false" the fadeout only started after the previous animation was completed. Thanks!

Comment: @Kobbe exactly. By default different `animate` calls work as a queue. We need to override that to be able to make them work overlapped and with a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("div").animate({left:"500px"},{duration:1000,start:function(){
   $(this).animate({opacity:"0"},400);
}});
```

or:

```
$("div").animate({left:"500px"},{duration:10000, queue:false,start:function(){
    $(this).delay(6000).animate({opacity:"0"},4000);
}});
```

Comment: Thank you Madalin Ivascu